# Do the ranged effects of districts or the Colosseum depend on the actual district location or on the city center?

Tags: civilization-6

Some districts (e.g. Factories, Zoos) and the Colosseum wonder have an effect that is stated to extend to cities within a range of 6 tiles.

Will this distance be calculated from the **district** itself or from its **city center**?

example: city A is 5 tiles away from city B - does A always get all ranged effects from B's districts? 
Or could districts on the far side of B fail to influence A?

Conversely, could a district on the near side of city C (itself 7+ tiles from A) influence A?

Comment: Pretty sure it's the city center, not the district, but no way to back that up right now

Comment: I've actually been taking for granted it was the district / wonder itself. Can't check right now sadly

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT:** As of the wnter update, it seems it no longer works the same way.
From the patchnotes:

> Cities can no longer receive yields from more than one regional building per type; they take the highest (ex. production from multiple Factories)
>   
> Cities can no longer receive amenities from more than one regional building per type; they take the highest (ex. amenities from multiple Stadiums)

I came back home and tested it, it just so happens that I have a perfect example to answer this in my current game.

TL;DR : The bonus extends from the **District** itself, not the city center.

[image]

As you can see here, both Kwila and Kwango have industrial districts. By hovering over the city's production, I can see that Kwila receives a +6 from factory while Kwango only receives +3 from factory.

Both cities are 7 tiles from each other, and no other cities or districts of my own are within range of Kwila, so we must assume that Kwila is getting its +3 bonus from Kwango's industrial district, which is exactly 6 tiles away. Meanwhile, Kwango does NOT receive a +3 bonus from Kwila's factory, which is in the industrial district 7 tiles away (which is poorly placed, in hindsight), like the city center.

I will also assume this will work the same way with wonders, though I have no way to back it up right now. It also makes sense IMO, as it makes positioning of your districts and wonders a lot more important.

Comment: thanks a lot. Makes district placement more of a headache, but at least the method is clear

Comment: @Chieron Yes, but it adds a lot of depth to city/district placement and requires planning much earlier. It's a nice little mini-game. :)

Comment: @DavidHarkness true. And I appreciate it. If only the map allowed markers, so that proper planning could be done. Or show the range when placing. I absolutely loathe to count this repeatedly. Doesn't help that I prefer Germany as civ..

Comment: @Chieron Check out the [Quick UI mod](https://github.com/chaorace/cqui). It adds a bunch of [district pins](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4a64c395e011230ba77e1420ab94649ef82567c2/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f4d3131746163362e706e67) and much more. You still have to count, but people have made some [cool new lenses](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/more-lenses.606150/), and I'd bet we'll see a [city/district planning lens](https://github.com/chaorace/cqui/issues/31) soon.

Comment: I think that cities can only receive the bonus from one copy of each building in a district, so even if Kwila's factory was in range of Kwango's City Center, Kwango would only get the benefit from one factory. This changed back in the Winter update: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289159/do-bonus-extending-building-factory-zoo-stack