# Which districts can be shared between multiple cities?

Tags: civilization-6

I have read - but can't find the link (and as usual Civipedia sucks) - that Entertainment districts can be shared between cities up to 6 tiles away.

I found the districts '[cheat sheet](https://mic.com/articles/157475/civ-6-districts-cheat-sheet-how-to-plan-your-cities-perfectly-in-one-chart#.ysZ2OrWJd)' on a number of sites but it doesn't mention this.

Is this true - and can any other districts be shared between multiple cities?

If so at what tile distance - and is there a city limit within that distance? Are all benefits shared or only some buildings?

How can you check which districts are affecting which cities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, only the entertainment and industrial districts share bonuses to nearby cities (along with the Colosseum wonder) and only the buildings who specify shared bonuses will do so.

Tile distance - [Do the ranged effects of districts or the Colosseum depend on the actual district location or on the city center?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289381/do-the-ranged-effects-of-districts-or-the-colloseum-depend-on-the-actual-distric/289432#289432)

Benefits shared - [Do "Bonus extending" building (Factory, Zoo, ...) stack?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289159/do-bonus-extending-building-factory-zoo-stack/289429#289429) (No city limit I believe, or it is more than 4 at least.)

Finally this is covered a bit in the other posts, but by hovering over the production of a particular city, you can see how much production it receives from particular buildings. No way to tell which city provides the bonuses, but it's easy enough to figure out which districts are within 6 tiles.

Comment: Thanks - do we have an exhaustive list of all districts that can be shared? I also assume 6 tiles doesn't include the tile the district is on?

Comment: Indeed, 6 tiles away from district works. I suppose you mean a list of buildings that can be shared? Off the top of my head I believe it's only Factory and Power Plant in Industrial district and Zoo/Stadium in entertainment, but I might be missing a few.

Comment: Only those buildings and their unique replacements (Japanese electronic factory, for example) provide AOE benefits. Additionally, the Colosseum provides AOE amenities and culture. I don't think any other wonder or building does.

Comment: So the complete list: Factory, Power Plant, Zoo, Stadium, Colosseum, + all replacements?